# jQuery Odometer

Tags: php, jquery

I would like to implement a jQuery odometer, similar to opower.com's website. So far, I was able to get a bit of the copied code to work, but there is such much extra code around their odometer script, my copied code is bloated and cumbersome, plus has incredible amount of styling that I do not like.

What I would like is a text based jQuery count-up odometer that can easily be packaged up in a nice clean folder.

- timer
- css
- html
- images

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

Don't mean to drag up an old thread, but I ran into a similar requirement a while back and ended up building my own solution. It's similar to the [setInterval method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7180814/116782); however, it has a more graphical UI on top. It's text-based and degrades gracefully on older browsers.

- [Blog post](http://nleach.com/post/16045448547/odometer-style-counter-using-jquery)
- [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jDkzg/)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at these: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/odoTicker

Comment: Yes I have...but that uses images, not text.

Answer (score 1):

Using the function `setInterval`, you can create a simple counter, similar to the link you provided. I made a quick example here. http://jsfiddle.net/ABrunkhorst/gacNE/

A random number between 1 and 5 is added every 250 milliseconds.

Comment: now, I am supposing to make the text update a div instead of an input box, I can use this in the javascript document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML;

Comment: Indeed. I updated this fiddle to use a div. http://jsfiddle.net/ABrunkhorst/gacNE/1/

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who may come across this same need, I recommend: http://github.hubspot.com/odometer/

You add the script `<script src="../odometer.js"></script>`, tag a div containing your starting number with the class `odometer` and drop the following script at the bottom of your page before the closing tag:

```
<script>
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.odometer').text(240000); //THIS IS THE TIME IT ROTATES TO
  }, 500);//THIS IS THE DURATION TIME IT TAKES TO GET THERE
</script>
```